# NullPointerException for ListView using CustomAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

CustomAdapter File included...

1.Initializing ArrayList.

2.Initializing ListView.

3.Grapping the Data from URL and storing in ArrayList

4.Setting ListView with CustomAdapter

5.Please check the CustomAdapter code which below the MainActivity..

```
public class Screen2 extends AppCompatActivity {     

ProgressDialog pDialog;
        ArrayList<Information> record_list;
        ListView list_view;
        CustomAdapter listAdapter;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.screen2);
            record_list=new ArrayList<Information>();
            list_view=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
            new Test().execute();
        }

        public class Test extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<Information>> {
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                super.onPreExecute();

                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Screen2.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<Information> doInBackground(String... params) {

                String jsonStr = makeServiceCall();
                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonStr);
                    for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                        JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id=jsonObject.getString("id");
                        String name=jsonObject.getString("label");
                        String email=jsonObject.getString("email");
                        Information information=new Information(id,name,email);
                        record_list.add(information);
                        return record_list;
                    }
                    System.out.println(jsonStr);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Information> s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                //listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(Screen2.this,record_list);
                listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(Screen2.this,record_list);
                list_view.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
            }

            public String makeServiceCall(){
                String response = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.109:9000/tasks2");
                    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    // read the response
                    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                    response = convertStreamToString(in);
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    System.out.println("MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                    System.out.println("MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
                }
                return response;
            }

            private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line;
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line).append('\n');
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(sb);
                return sb.toString();
            }
        }

}
```

CustomAdapter.java:(Here is my CustomAdapter File)
I don't see any error in this file too...

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Information> {

        public CustomAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Information> record) {
            super(c, R.layout.custom_row, record);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            // Get the data item for this position

            Information information = getItem(position);

            //LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(getContext());

            // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view

            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

            // Lookup view for data population

            TextView record_id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.record_id);

            TextView record_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.record_name);

            TextView record_email = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.record_email);

            // Populate the data into the template view using the data object

            record_id.setText(information.id);
            record_name.setText(information.name);
            record_email.setText(information.email);

            return convertView;
        }
}
```

Comment: add your json response with your question.

Comment: Extracted JSON Response:I/System.out: id: 2name:Physiotherapyemailhariprasad.sala@gmail.com
I/System.out: id: 3name:Cardiologyemailhariprasad.sala@gmail.com
I/System.out: id:5name:FirstGooseDoesemailhariprasad.sala@gmail.com
I/System.out: id: 9name:BestOneemailhariprasad.sala@gmail.com
I/System.out: id: 17name:Overallemailhariprasad.sala@gmail.com
I/System.out: id: 19name:Androidemailhariprasad.sala@gmail.com

Comment: Guy's Thanks a alot for your time...., that was a small confusion with layouts, Forgot to changes the ListView id for my Screen Size Layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are logical errors in code:

1. The `for` loop has a `return` statement inside it while you have to iterate so do this for a good design define another variable for `Arraylist` lets say `s` and the code would look like this:

   ```
   @Override
   protected ArrayList<Information> doInBackground(String... params) {

       String jsonStr = makeServiceCall();
       ArrayList<Information> s = new ArrayList<Information>();
       try {
           JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonStr);
           for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
               JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
               String id=jsonObject.getString("id");
               String name=jsonObject.getString("label");
               String email=jsonObject.getString("email");
               Information information=new Information(id,name,email);
               s.add(information); 
           }
           System.out.println(jsonStr);
           return s;
       } catch (JSONException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return null;
   }
   ```
2. Then on your `onPostExecute` make `record_list` be `s` like this:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<Information> s) {
       super.onPostExecute(s);
       // Dismiss the progress dialog
       //listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(Screen2.this,record_list);
       record_list = s;
       listAdapter=new CustomAdapter(Screen2.this,record_list);
       list_view.setAdapter(listAdapter);
       if (pDialog.isShowing())
           pDialog.dismiss();

       /**
        * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
        * */
   }
   ```

Comment: Tried changing to above, still have the same Exception.

Comment: Which line does the log say it has a problem? The line that appear in blue!

Comment: list_view.setAdapter(listAdapter); @ onPostExecute.

Comment: What gets printed on logs by this line of code does this say `System.out.println(jsonStr);`

Comment: It prints JSON string which I've extracted from URL...

Comment: I/System.out: [{"id":2,"label":"Physiotherapy","image":"/9j/7QAsUGhvd.....}]

Comment: does `"email"` exist?

Comment: Yes, I've already extracted those value's from JSON data and displayed on to my screen. They are very much there...

Comment: If you real updated the `onPostExecute` and `doBackground` code like I have shown you then there is no more problem there! I am doubting your `CustomAdapter` edit the question add it!

Comment: Guy's Thanks a alot for your time...., that was a small confusion with layouts, Forgot to changes the ListView id for my Screen Size Layout.

Comment: @Hari I am glad you solved the problem **Happy Coding!**.

Comment: Thank You...Wish you the same.